# Is pointerEvents: 'box-none' broken in React 18.1.0?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-18

We've been using pointerEvents: 'box-none' for a particular View where we want the things behind it to be clickable. From the React docs: https://reactnative.dev/docs/view

'box-none': The View is never the target of touch events but its subviews can be. It behaves like if the view had the following classes in CSS:

```
.box-none {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.box-none * {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

But we just updated to React 18, and now that view seems to be snagging all of the pointer events instead of letting them pass through to the background.

Any ideas what might be going wrong? Any fix suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

From React docs in the yellow box:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/view#pointerevents

"Since pointerEvents does not affect layout/appearance, and we are already deviating from the spec by adding additional modes, we opt to not include pointerEvents on style. On some platforms, we would need to implement it as a className anyways. Using style or not is an implementation detail of the platform."

so you need to put it as direct prop on the ViewElement like this:

```
<View pointerEvents="box-none"></View>
```

instead of:

```
<View style={{pointerEvents: 'box-none'}}></View>
```